# Shorten A String in Angular/Typescript And Expand Later When Using It

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, qr-code, url-shortener

I have a string that is 928 characters that I am using to create a qr code for. The issue I am having is that, although the QR code scans fine on Iphone, android devices seem to struggle detect it. I believe this is due to the size of the QR code. I wanted to know if there was a way I could truncate that 928 character string to under 50 characters and then expand it when I use it after scanning the QR Code. Upon researching, I found many QR question and a lot of questions on how to shorten text, but nothing specifically relating to my question.

The QR HTML is:

```
<qrcode
        [qrdata]="qrUrl"
        [allowEmptyString]="true"
        [attr.ariaLabel]="'QR Code image with the following content...'"
        [cssClass]="'center'"
        [colorDark]="'#000000ff'"
        [colorLight]="'#ffffffff'"
        [elementType]="'canvas'"
        [errorCorrectionLevel]="'M'"
        [attr.imageSrc]="currentUser.imageData ? currentUser.imageData : './assets/default-logo.png'"
        [attr.imageHeight]="75"
        [attr.imageWidth]="75"
        [margin]="4"
        [scale]="1"
        [title]="'A custom title attribute'"
        [width]="300"
      ></qrcode>
```

Comment: "I believe this is due to ..." What's the evidence? 928 characters is totally fine for a QR code. What do you use to generate and scan the QR code? Have you try adjusting the error correction level when generating the QR code?

Comment: I use angularx-qrcode to generate the QR code. I updated the question to show the html code for the qr

Comment: If your device struggle to scan the code, you can try to set errorCorrectionLevel to 'L', which will give you a smaller code. Also keep your camera steady for a while, old devices do take some time to process the scan.

Comment: If you want to reduce the data, there is no magic that can truncate your string then give you back the lost information out of no where. Depend on the data structure and the usage, you may come up with a suitable way to optimize the data.

Comment: well theoretically, if the QR code would send the user to a web site, with some kind of an id, and that website can then pull all the data from the server, based on that id, it can then ,do whatever you want, including, if needed for some reason, redirect back to the app with the extra information. the `url` behind the QR code can be quite small. depending on use case I could be totally off here though

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, Stavm I am doing something similar here and @Ricky Mo your solution to change the error correction to L fixed the issue. Can you please explain the error correction on QR more as most explanations I looked at online seems to be vague and confusing.

Comment: I seem to be getting this error in prod whereas the url works in dev when changing the error correction to L.
[angularx-qrcode] canvas error:  Error: The amount of data is too big to be stored in a QR Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the error correction to L fixed the issue.